# Static mapping of array index and array content in C

Tags: c, arrays, struct, macros, c-preprocessor

I am having a list of parameters. Each parameter is defined by an unique identifier (`ParamID`) and some other data (`&ParamX`, `SomeOtherDataX`) associated with this parameter. All the available parameters are organized in a table, which is implemented as a struct array (`ParameterList[]`) in **C**. Thus, on each row I can see all associated data for one parameter. The following code snippet should (hopefully) make this clearer:

```
// predefined IDs; not changeable!
#define PARAM_ID_A   10
#define PARAM_ID_B   12
#define PARAM_ID_C   14

// the basic structure of my parameter list
typedef struct ParameterList_t {
  int    ParamID,
  *int   ParamAddr,
  *float SomeConnectedData
}

// definition of my list in ROM
const ParameterList_t ParameterList[] = {
  { PARAM_ID_A, &Param1, SomeOtherData1},
  { PARAM_ID_B, &Param2, SomeOtherData2},
  { PARAM_ID_C, &Param3, SomeOtherData3}
};
```

Now I want to create another list, which contains references on a subset of the parameters defined in the `ParameterList[]` table. This list should also be resided in ROM. I basically want to access all associated data for a subset of the parameters.

```
const *ParameterList_t ParameterSubListA[] = {
     &ParameterList[2],   // parameter: PARAM_ID_B
     &ParameterList[3],   // parameter: PARAM_ID_C
};
```

The problem here is that the code will be maintained by many people and the parameter list (`ParameterList[]`) might change frequently and parameters will be sorted into the table at the beginning or in the middle. This means the sub list (`ParameterSubListA[]`) must be updated to point to the desired parameters if their index (index = row in `ParameterList[]`) changes.

**Question:**

*Basically my code needs a mapping from `ParamID` to the index of the `ParameterList[]` table, preferably by use of the preprocessor and only in ROM. I found different ways to implement this, which are all not satisfying:*

**Option 1:**

Automatically generate a list in the RAM at startup, which maps the ParamID to the index in ParameterList[]. What I get is an array, that could be called `CrossRefTable[]`:

```
IndexOfParameterA_InParameterList = CrossRefTable[PARAM_ID_A];
```

My sublist would then look like this (cannot be constant anymore :/ ):

```
*ParameterList_t ParameterSubListA[] = {
     &ParameterList[CrossRefTable[PARAM_ID_B]],   // parameter: PARAM_ID_B
     &ParameterList[CrossRefTable[PARAM_ID_C]],   // parameter: PARAM_ID_C
};
```

I am short of RAM, so I would prefer a solution that only uses ROM.

**Option 2:**

Use a predefined macro `__COUNTER__`, which increments with each call and generate a macro in each row:

```
const ParameterList_t ParameterList[] = {
  { PARAM_ID_A, &Param1, SomeOtherData1},
  #define PARAM_IDX_A __COUNTER__
  { PARAM_ID_B, &Param2, SomeOtherData2},
  #define PARAM_IDX_B __COUNTER__
  { PARAM_ID_C, &Param3, SomeOtherData3}
  #define PARAM_IDX_C __COUNTER__
};
```

My sublist would then look like this:

```
const *ParameterList_t ParameterSubListA[] = {
     &ParameterList[PARAM_IDX_B],   // parameter: PARAM_ID_B
     &ParameterList[PARAM_IDX_C],   // parameter: PARAM_ID_C
};
```

I would favorise this option, apparently it is not possible to use GCC.

**Other Options:**
I also figured there might be a possiblity in using X-MACROS, but I am not sure about that.
Boost is also not an option.

Hopefully my explanation is somehow clear...

Comment: Does that even work? Its been a while since I worked on an embedded system, but I find it surprising that a compiler can properly put `&something_else_I_just_compiled_into_ROM` into ROM.

Comment: I thought I'd get a compile error if something in my const definition is not really constant a compile time. Therefore I figured this goes into ROM. Is that thought right?

Comment: @Simon, C has no concept of ROM.  Moreover, `const`-qualified variables *cannot* go into ROM unless you're writing firmware, because nothing that has to be *loaded into memory* can be loaded into ROM.  If it happens that you *are* writing firmware, then you'll need to consult your toolchain's documentation to determine how to arrange for variables to be assigned storage in the firmware image (i.e. in ROM), but it is not necessarily related to being `const` qualified.

Comment: Yes, actually I am writing firmware for a DSP, which uses flash as non-volatile memory. I will take a deeper look into the toolchain, but I was relying on the current configuration to put `const` variables into flash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the data is static, I'd say go on and initialize it statically. 
Using external tools if the compiler is not capable enough.

parameter_list.c:

```
const struct ParameterList_t ParameterList[] = {
    { PARAM_ID_A, &Param1, SomeOtherData1},
    { PARAM_ID_C, &Param2, SomeOtherData2},
    { PARAM_ID_B, &Param3, SomeOtherData3}
};

#include "parameter_list_index.h"

const *ParameterList_t ParameterSubListA[] = {
    &ParameterList[PARAM_ID_C_INDEX],
    &ParameterList[PARAM_ID_B_INDEX],
};
```

parameter_list.px:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -n
print "#define $1_INDEX ".($n++)."\n" if
    /^const.*ParameterList\[\]/../^}/ and /^\s*{\s*([^,]+)/;
```

Makefile:

```
parameter_list.o: parameter_list.c parameter_list.h

parameter_list_index.h: parameter_list.c
    ./parameter_list.px $< > $@
```

This is just a general idea, your implementation may differ of course.
You may choose to generate `ParameterList[]` the same way or use [PARAM_ID_A_INDEX] = { ... } to make extra sure the indexes match.

Note the code above relies heavily on formatting, which may or may not be ok.
 And in any case, some people may find tricks like this inappropriate.

Comment: Using scripts seems like a very efficient way to solve this to me. Didn't think about it, though. Anyway, I could change the toolchain on my computer, yet the other people who work on the code may not. So unfortunately, this will not work in my case. Thanks for the good input!

Answer (score 0):

Were I doing this, and I needed flexibility

Then I would have defined an enum that matches the table of data.
(no actual instance of the enum needed, just the definition

Then declared an array that contains some values from the enum.

The values in that array are the offsets into the data array

Comment: You mean declare an enum like: `typedef enum = {ParamID, ParamAddr, Data}` for one row of my ParameterList ?